# How do I control text alignment in a document with a  3 column layout in Pages 09?

Tags: pages, iwork, formatting, design

How do I create a menu/brochure for a salon with 3 columns, where the price will be next to the description but right-aligned?

I think there has to be be a better way than hitting the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar to get it to the right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got tabular data (which it sounds like you do), using a table is perfectly appropriate.

The other way is with tabs. Show the ruler by hitting command-R (if it's not already visible). You should see triangles denoting the margins of the page. Click anywhere in the ruler to create a tab stop. Create some more. By default, tab stops are left-aligning, but if you double-click on an existing tab stop you cycle through center-aligning, right-aligning, and decimal-aligning (useful for lining up numbers like $100.10 and $100.).

Once you've got your tabs, start entering some text, with tabs where appropriate. If you want to adjust the tab stops, make sure to select the text it applies to first.

If you want to get really smart, once you've got everything set up exactly the way you like, you'll create a style. Hit command-shift-T to show the styles drawer (if it's not already visible), and click the + at the bottom of the drawer. Create a new paragraph style and call it whatever you want. Then you can apply it consistently to new text in the document.

Using columns to do this is possible but awkward. Using spaces is a bad idea because the text will never line up right—plus it's a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually handle this sort of problem is to put all of the information in a 3 column table but hide all of the cell borders. This gives plenty of control over the formatting of each of the columns.

Comment: Creating a 3 column was already done. But I'm having problem with putting the price on each column to the right of the description. Probably using table is the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: I missed this before, but if you've already got a column for the numbers, you can just make the whole column right-aligned. Select the column, and then in the menubar select Format:Text:Align Right

Answer (score 0):

Well to use a table is one option but there are some more elegant solutions which are built right into the Pages.

In the "Template Chooser" you can find many 3 column layouts which you could in principle take and modify and finish with that.

Or you could do it all by yourself here is how: You open a blank page (preferably in landscape mode) and open the inspector. In the Layout tab you can create as many columns as you wish. This can also be done with a toolbar icon which is usually not present by default and create equally spaced 2, 3 and 4 columns.